# Is it possible to send selected code(whole documents) to the gedit terminal for execution?

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, gedit, tools

I want to use external tools to automate the internal execution of presently-being-authored scripts by keyboard shortcut. The only thing I can find on this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019841/how-to-send-and-execute-current-line-of-code-in-gedit-to-terminal-using-external). But I think it must be out of date because it's producing a syntax error that I can't find any useful information on. I know python3 needs parentheses after `print`, so I tried with and without, but the same error is produced. Strangely, `print commands.getoutput(line))` produces a syntax error recognizing the missing opening parenthesis.

Also I changed the 'comment'(I guess) at the top of the tool to `python3` thinking the interpreter would handle whatever parentheses indiscretion was occurring a little more gracefully, but that's a no go because `commands` is apparently defunct now.

Obviously I want the code that will do what I want, but answers shedding light on the error as well are preferred. I care to know what's actually happening.

**EDIT**
[Proof that my syntax is accurate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHvGs.png)

**EDIT**
I realized that the issue might be something to do with my code, because previously I was working with a multi-page length script, so I opened a new document and tried the following simple statements. The results are interesting but tell me nothing.

Input

```
True == True
```

Output

```
Running tool: run source

sh: 1: True: not found


Done.
```

Um, okay.

---

Input

```
True==True
```

Output

```
Running tool: run source



Done.
```

Oh! Maybe it did the calculation but it just didn't print it!

---

Input

```
print(True==True)
```

Output

```
Running tool: run source

sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")


Done.
```

... Back to square one I guess.

---

Input

```
print True==True
```

Output

```
Running tool: run source

sh: 2: Syntax error: ";" unexpected


Done.
```

What f***ing semicolon?!

**EDIT** So I thought I had the problem worked out below. Not so much it turns out... I've just realized this doesn't answer the question! I asked if it is possible to send selected code to the gedit TERMINAL for execution. The idea was to have an IDLE like set up where I could arm the terminal with classes, functions and variables from my document and then interact with it live. External tools make use of an 'Output panel' which gets put in a tab beside the embedded python terminal. It executes the code behind the scenes and then displays the full output all at the same time. It can't be used to get user input.

Comment: It's not a gedit issue - you got Python 3's `print` syntax wrong - the correct one is: `print(commands.getoutput(line))` - You need *both* an opening and closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the errors read the way they did, but by pure luck I did author a functioning code...

It goes like this:

Plugin

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

exec(sys.stdin.read())
```

-Shortcut key: Alt+R ---or whatever you're comfortable with

-Save: Nothing

-Input: Current selection(default to document)

-Output: Display in the bottom pane

-Applicability: |All documents |Python 3

Input

```
print(True == True)
```

Output

```
Running tool: run source

True

Done.
```

**EDIT** I've just realized this doesn't answer the question! I asked if it is possible to send selected code to the gedit TERMINAL for execution. The idea was to have an IDLE like set up where I could arm the terminal with classes, functions and variables from my document and then interact with it live. External tools make use of an 'Output panel' which gets put in a tab beside the embedded python terminal. It executes the code behind the scenes and then displays the full output all at the same time. It can't be used to get user input.